# Unit of $eV^4$ for Density?

Tags: units

I'm going through [this paper](http://www.phys.cwru.edu/undergrad/Senior%20Projects/papers/papers2011/Elder_Starkman_2011%20S.pdf) on electroweak burning, and I ran across the figure  $100 GeV^4$ to describe energy density. I'd like an explanation as to how the units work out, and why this figure isn't just stated in eV/cm^3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Page 4 of the paper says it uses units were $c$, $k_B$ and $\hbar$ all equal $1$.

If energy has dimension $E$, and $L$, $T$ are the dimensions of length and time,  $\hbar$ has dimension $ET$ and $c$ has dimensions $LT^{-1}$.

So $L$ is equivalent to $c\hbar/E$.

Energy density has dimensions $E/L^3$ = $E^4/(c\hbar)^3$ which is numerically the same as $E^4$.